# Issue with SMTP connection closing after issuing STARTTLS command

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail, telnet, postfix-mta

I'm currently working on a project that involves connecting to an SMTP server(locally) using telnet and initiating a TLS connection using the STARTTLS command. However, after successfully establishing the TLS connection, any subsequent commands result in the connection being closed with the message `Connection closed by foreign host.` Here is an example of the session:

```
Trying 192.168.1.54...
Connected to 192.168.1.54.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 localhost ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo 192.168.1.54
250-localhost
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250-SMTPUTF8
250 CHUNKING
starttls
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
mail from: omerkhan01234@gmail.com
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Expectation:
My expectation was to establish a successful SMTP connection, including the TLS connection, and be able to send an email through this connection. I anticipated being able to proceed with the SMTP session and complete the email sending process without the connection being closed unexpectedly.

Additional Information:

The SMTP server is running on Ubuntu with Postfix.
I'm trying to send mail.
I'm using telnet to manually interact with the SMTP server for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

After `STARTTLS`, you're supposed to initiate the TLS handshake. `telnet` doesn't do this for you. Since TLS is binary and involves cryptography, you cannot do this by hand. If you need to use TLS (since the connection is local, why don't you continue without?), you have to use `openssl`. Example:

```
openssl s_client -quiet -crlf -starttls smtp -connect gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25
```

If you use SMTP for submitting instead of relaying a message and your server supports implicit TLS, you can skip the `-starttls smtp` option. Example:

```
openssl s_client -quiet -crlf -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
```

Comment: I used `openssl` to send emails via `SMTP`, and I noticed that when I use the `rcpt to` command with an invalid email address, I don't receive any error message. Here are the steps I'm following: 
https://gist.github.com/Mubashir01234/0248c41a207256152f75b93174947395

Comment: If the incoming mail server determines that your message is likely spam, it drops the message without a bounce message in order to prevent so-called [backscatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_(email)). In order not to attract more spam, incoming mail servers won't tell you during the SMTP session whether a given email address exists locally. (PS: Please accept my answer above if it was useful. Based on your gist, it seems it was.)